# GoogleMaps com duas APIs?

Tags: google-maps

Estou trabalhando em uma pagina com varias chamadas das funções dessa biblioteca, 
acontece que, tenho duas referencias  para chamar a API e, cada uma delas funciona com apenas uma parte das funções que preciso,

> Por exemplo se chamo:

```
< script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyGoogleKey&libraries=drawing&callback=initMap" 
    async defer >
< /script >
```

consigo ter acesso a caixa de desenho, mas aparece erro  para a funcao **GBrowserIsCompatible**

```
"Uncaught ReferenceError: GBrowserIsCompatible is not defined"
```

> Na minha segunda tentativa chamei assim:

```
< script src="https://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=3&key=MyGoogleKey&libraries=drawing" 
    type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" >
< /script >
```

Consigo chamar "GBrowserIsCompatible" MAS, a caixa de desenho nem aparece.... e da erro na funcao **DrawingManager** (que eh da caixa de desenho)

```
"Uncaught ReferenceError: DrawingManager is not defined"
```

> LEMBRANDO:
>   Cada método funciona perfeitamente quando rodando separadamente,

Por favor onde estou errando?
eis um exemplo do codigo:
tambem coloquei no  [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Yamamila/pen/Qgaojw?editors=1000)

```
    <html>

    <head>
      <title>Drawing tools</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <style>
        /**
         *   Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
         *   element that contains the map.
         */

        html, body, #map_canvas {
          height: 500px;
          width: 500px;
          margin: 0px;
          padding: 0px
        }
      </style>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div id="map_canvas" style=" border: 2px solid #3872ac;">
      </div>
      <div id="info">
      </div>
      <div id="info2">
      </div>


<html>

<head>
  <title>Drawing tools</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">



      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <style>
    /**
     *   Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
     *   element that contains the map.
     */

    html, body, #map_canvas {
      height: 500px;
      width: 500px;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
    }
  </style>
  <!-- 
    -   parando de usar o google maps na versao 2
    -->

  <!-- 
  <script src="https://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=3&key=AIzaSyDlSu5oKxhwIXvZ9c3ZVLGn-2rHvVC4EV0&libraries=drawing"             type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  </script>
  -->

</head>

<body>
  <div id="map_canvas" style=" border: 2px solid #3872ac;">
  </div>
  <div id="info">
  </div>
  <div id="info2">
  </div>


  <script>
    function initMap() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
        center: {
          lat: 35.362152270911,
          lng: 132.75379295934
        },
        zoom: 13
      });

      var drawingManager2 = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
        drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
        drawingControl: true,
        drawingControlOptions: {
          position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
          drawingModes: ['marker', 'circle', 'polygon', 'polyline', 'rectangle']
          // drawingModes: ['rectangle']
        }
      });

      console.log(drawingManager2)
      drawingManager2.setMap(map)

      google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager2, 'polygoncomplete', function(polygon) {
        document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += "polygon points:" + "<br>";
        for (var i = 0; i < polygon.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
          document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += polygon.getPath().getAt(i).toUrlValue(6) + "<br>";
        }
        <!-- polygonArray.push(polygon); -->
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager2, 'rectanglecomplete', function(rectangle) {
        var ne = rectangle.getBounds().getNorthEast();
        var sw = rectangle.getBounds().getSouthWest();

        document.getElementById('info').innerHTML +=
        ne.lat() + ', ' + ne.lng() + '<br>' +
        sw.lat() + ', ' + sw.lng();
      });
    }


    function initialize() {
     if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
       map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
       map.setCenter(new GLatLng(35.565486108000073,133.04002472100001), 13);

       var points1 = [
           new GLatLng(35.565486108000073,133.04002472100001)
       ];
       var polygon1 = new GPolygon(points1);
       map.addOverlay(polygon1);
     }
    }

  $(document).ready(function(){
      initialize();
  });


  </script>
  <!-- 
    -   chamando o google maps na versao 3
    -->
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBLk1GHCv9vQwx6N1TY19fFMrASoVh-vJk&libraries=drawing&callback=initMap" async defer>
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Qual parte não funciona? Rodando no Codepen, aparece a caixa de desenho e os dois listeners estão executando.

Comment: **Bom dia!** Bom passei o final de semana revendo isso em casa, e acho que, nao sei como explicar melhor, pois o mesmo erro continua. Então Comentei  melhor o exemplo do CodePen, ONDE **___1)**   se chamado a API pelas linhas 27 a 32, "GBrowserIsCompatible()" funciona sem problemas, *MAS o Box de desenho nao*,  **___2)** do outro lado, se "chamado" a API pelas linhas 131 a linha 136, o box de desenho e que para. ENTAO: como sera que eu poderia fazer pra explicar melhor esse erro...  pois .. **___3)** PRECISO  da função **GBrowserIsCompatible()** e do box de desenho funcionando simultaneamente!

Comment: Quando se alterna as chamadas para a API, (ou se coloca as duas simultaneas)  os erros e alertas vao aparecendo no console do Inspector... **por exemplo:** *Uncaught ReferenceError: GBrowserIsCompatible is not defined*   **ou ainda** *You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.*

Comment: Pelo o que entendi no site https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2tov3?hl=pt-br   ,  a versao 3 do googleMaps (que permite o box de desenho) nao tem mais aquelas funções... que me são importantes. por exemplo **GLatLng** que foi trocada por **google.maps.LatLng**  ENTAO, vou ter uma grande dor de cabeça pra aprender a usar essas novas funções.

Comment: BOM me parece que agora simplesmente posso parar de usar **GBrowserIsCompatible**  e trocar a função **GMap2()**  por **google.maps.Map**, o que me pareceu facil, pelos exemplos da pagina *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12500654/uncaught-referenceerror-google-is-not-defined*  ___MAS, esta dano um erro novo... **Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined**.....   aceito mais ajuda e dicas para resolver isso...

Comment: Nessa atualização que você colocou tem um problema que é a função `initialize`. Ela é chamada antes da API do Maps ter carregado. Você deve chamar as funções do mapa na função `initMap`.